# Unable to change data types of certain columns read from xslx and by Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I import an Excel file with pandas and when I try to convert all columns to float64 for further manipulation. I have several columns that have a type like:

0
column_name_1 float64
column_name_1 float64
dtype: object

and it is unable to do any calculations. May I ask how I could change this column type to float64?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to change the datatype of columns in pandas,

Have you tried using the astype() function, Visit the official documentation below for more information and usage examples,

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: Yeah I had tried that. I just solved it yesterday and it is because I have two same columns in the Data frame and it causes that when I try to access pd['something'] it automatically combine two columns together and then it becomes an object instead of float64

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it yesterday and it is because I have two same columns in the Data frame and it causes that when I try to access pd['something'] it automatically combine two columns together and then it becomes an object instead of float64